# Dúvida ao configurar relacionamento de entidades

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, code-first

Numa hipótese, possuo uma entidade para cadastro de endereços:

```
 public class Endereco
    {
        [Key]
        public int EnderecoId { get; set; }

        public string TipoLogradouro { get; set; }

        public string Logradouro { get; set; }

        public string NumLogradouro { get; set; }

        public string Complemento { get; set; }

        public string Bairro { get; set; }

        public int UFId { get; set; }

        public virtual Estado UF { get; set; }

        public int CidadeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }

        public string CEP { get; set; }

        public bool Cobranca { get; set; }

        public bool Entrega { get; set; }

        public bool Fatura { get; set; }

        public int PessoaId { get; set; }

        public virtual IPessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Essa classe possui as propriedades virtuais `UF` e `Cidade`, como todo bom endereço que se preze.

Mas, ao configurar os relacionamentos do `Entity` me deparei com a seguinte dúvida: Se, por motivos óbvios, toda classe `cidade` terá necessariamente uma propriedade `uf` relacionada, eu precisaria declarar a propriedade `uf` também na classe `Endereco`?

A resposta mais óbvia para mim seria `NÃO`, mas, nesse caso, qual seria então a forma mais correta de gerar uma `View` para cadastrar um endereço? E isso não "dificultaria", por exemplo, uma consulta de clientes de um determinado estado?

Comment: A opção de replicar ou não o dado uf na entidade endereço é pessoal. Vai depender das suas necessidades... Por exemplo, se não existir uf em endereço então ao se cadastrar um novo endereço o usuário será obrigado a aceitar a uf que vier quando ele selecionar a cidade. Agora, caso vc queira deixar ele alterar a uf então o campo uf tem que estar na entidade endereço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se, por motivos óbvios, toda classe cidade terá necessariamente uma propriedade uf relacionada, eu precisaria declarar a propriedade uf também na classe Endereco?

Se `Endereco` pertence a uma `Cidade`, não.

> Qual seria então a forma mais correta de gerar uma *View* para cadastrar um endereço?

Num sistema que escrevo, meus *Models* são assim:

```
[DisplayColumn("Descricao")]
[Table("Logradouros")]
public class Logradouro : IEntidade, IPesquisavel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid LogradouroId { get; set; }
    public Guid BairroId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(450)]
    public String Descricao { get; set; }
    public String DescricaoFonetizado { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [DisplayName("CEP")]
    public int Cep { get; set; }

    public virtual Bairro Bairro { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Termo de Pesquisa")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public String TermoPesquisa
    {
        get { return Descricao + ", " + Cep.ToString(); }
        private set { }
    }

    [DisplayName("Última Modificação")]
    public DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Criação")]
    public String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Modificação")]
    public String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}

[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
[Table("Bairros")]
public class Bairro : IEntidade, IPesquisavel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BairroId { get; set; }
    public Guid CidadeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(450)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String NomeAbreviado { get; set; }
    public String NomeFonetizado { get; set; }

    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Logradouro> Logradouros { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<AgenciaBancaria> AgenciasBancarias { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ClientePrevidenciario> ClientesPrevidenciario { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Reclamante> Reclamantes { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Termo de Pesquisa")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public String TermoPesquisa
    {
        get { return Nome; }
        private set { }
    }

    [DisplayName("Última Modificação")]
    public DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Criação")]
    public String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Modificação")]
    public String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}

[Table("Cidades")]
public class Cidade : IEntidade, IPesquisavel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CidadeId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Estado")]
    public Guid EstadoId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Código da Cidade no SAPC")]
    public int RcrCidadeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome da cidade é obrigatório.")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(450)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Código no IBGE")]
    public int CodigoIbge { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Código no SIAFI")]
    public int CodigoSiafi { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("CEP")]
    public int? Cep { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Bairro> Bairros { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ClientePrevidenciario> ClientesPrevidenciario { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Reclamante> Reclamantes { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Foro> Foros { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Tribunal> Tribunais { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Termo de Pesquisa")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public String TermoPesquisa
    {
        get { return Nome; }
        private set { }
    }

    [DisplayName("Última Modificação")]
    public DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Criação")]
    public String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Modificação")]
    public String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}

[Table("Estados")]
public class Estado : IEntidade, IPesquisavel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EstadoId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("País")]
    public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome do país é obrigatório.")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A sigla do país é obrigatória.")]
    [DisplayName("Sigla")]
    public String Sigla { get; set; }

    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Termo de Pesquisa")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public String TermoPesquisa
    {
        get { return Nome; }
        private set { }
    }

    [DisplayName("Última Modificação")]
    public DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Criação")]
    public String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Modificação")]
    public String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}

[Table("Paises")]
public class Pais : IEntidade, IPesquisavel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome do país é obrigatório.")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A sigla do país é obrigatória.")]
    [DisplayName("Sigla")]
    public String Sigla { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Termo de Pesquisa")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public String TermoPesquisa
    {
        get { return Nome; }
        private set { }
    }

    [DisplayName("Última Modificação")]
    public DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data de Criação")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Criação")]
    public String UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Usuário da Modificação")]
    public String UsuarioModificacao { get; set; }
}
```

Um endereço seria ligado a um bairro, que seria ligado a uma cidade, que seria ligada a um estado, que seria ligado a um país.

> E isso não "dificultaria", por exemplo, uma consulta de clientes de um determinado estado?

Não, porque usando Entity Framework você pode pesquisar assim:

```
var enderecos = db.Enderecos.Where(e => e.Bairro.Cidade.EstadoId == id);
```

Comment: Ótimo! Estava pensando algo nesse caminho, apenas não sabia se era o ideal. Obrigado pelos exemplos.